# RecyclerView content appears behind BottomNavBar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, navigationbar

I've got a layout with a RecyclerView and a BottomNavBar :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mainNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items">
</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

When i start my activity, the last cardview appears behind the Navigation bar : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vPwKTwswDSTrf5IJga54fTahUB1j9hni.
When i add to me RecyclerView the line "android:layout_above="@+id/mainNav"", some strange this appears on the screen, my RecyclerView bug a lot : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vI6eOBIf6tQe0rw6wFDDO2phYNvrxRwX. Can you help me please ? <3

cardview.xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/CardVieww"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_nom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_lieu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_heure"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:padding="10dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Planning.java :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_planning);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Planning").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            ListNom.clear();
            ListHeure.clear();
            ListLieu.clear();
            Day.clear();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    ListNom.add(document.getString("Nom"));
                    ListHeure.add(document.getString("Heure"));
                    ListLieu.add(document.getString("Lieu"));
                    Day.add(document.getString("Day"));
                    RecyclerViewAdapter();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mainNav = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.mainNav);
    mainNav.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);
    mainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home :
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Planning.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_map :
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Planning.this, Localisation.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_search :
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(Planning.this, Search.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_planning :
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_contact :
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(Planning.this, Contact.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

public void RecyclerViewAdapter() {
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ListNom, ListHeure, ListLieu, Day);
    RecyclerView myView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    myView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    myView.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(Planning.this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    myView.setLayoutManager(llm);
}
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

public ArrayList<String> ListNom;
public ArrayList<String> ListHeure;
public ArrayList<String> ListLieu;
public ArrayList<String> Day;
public RecyclerViewAdapter (ArrayList<String> ListNom, ArrayList<String> ListHeure, ArrayList<String> ListLieu, ArrayList<String> Day){
    this.ListNom= ListNom;
    this.ListHeure= ListHeure;
    this.ListLieu= ListLieu;
    this.Day= Day;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(listItem);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(Day.get(position) == null){ holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); holder.myTextView.setText(ListNom.get(position)); }else {
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cac8a0"));
        holder.myTextView4.setText(ListNom.get(position)); }
    holder.myTextView2.setText(ListHeure.get(position));
    holder.myTextView3.setText(ListLieu.get(position));
    if(holder.myTextView3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){ holder.myTextView3.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ListNom.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView myTextView;
    private TextView myTextView2;
    private TextView myTextView3;
    private TextView myTextView4;
    private CardView cardView;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_nom);
        myTextView2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_heure);
        myTextView3 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_lieu);
        myTextView4 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_day);
        cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardVieww);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try adding the RecyclerView  tag at the end of your xml file and not before BottomNavigationView

Comment: Same thing, it don't work =/

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use a Constraint layout, you could constraint your list view to end at the top of the bar by adding the following line to your xml:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mainNav"
```

EDIT: You can easily convert your layout in a constraint one in Android Studio by going into the layout file in Design Mode and on your component tree right click on the relative layout and select convert layout to constraint layout, and Android Studio will do the rest.

[Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjtmafk6cfeAhVrAsAKHZIrCUkQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fconstraint-layout%2F&usg=AOvVaw1i8K6y_CkgHOgyT-8KVtA9)'s some more info on Constraint Layouts

Comment: It even don't works, my first cardiew and last cardview are cut

Comment: did you change it to constraint layout? could you post your code for that please?

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to the `RecyclerView`:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/mainNav"
```

so it will stay above the `BottomNavigationView` inside the `RelativeLayout`  
**Edit**:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    ListNom.clear();
    ListHeure.clear();
    ListLieu.clear();
    Day.clear();
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            ListNom.add(document.getString("Nom"));
            ListHeure.add(document.getString("Heure"));
            ListLieu.add(document.getString("Lieu"));
            Day.add(document.getString("Day"));
        }
        setRecyclerViewAdapter();
    }
}
```

Comment: It don't appears behind the BottomNavBar but the cardview's text bug, look : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XsMG1q3Q2vqp865etOm5UYTroBe5AuF7

Comment: The title of your question is "RecyclerView content appears behind BottomNavBar", but this is something else. You need to explain this problem. Where does this text come from? And post the cardview's xml.

Comment: It's done i have add cardview.xml and the 2 activities

Comment: Inside `onBindViewHolder()` replace all occurences of `position` with `holder.getAdapterPosition()` and try it.

Comment: Inside `Planning.java` you have a method `public void RecyclerViewAdapter()`. Why did you give it the same name as the class `RecyclerViewAdapter`? Change it to `setRecyclerViewAdapter`. Then make the change that I will post in my answer.

Comment: Give it one more try: remove `myView.setHasFixedSize(true);` from `setRecyclerViewAdapter()`

Comment: Nope, i think i'm going to let the last card behind the navbar and set blank content to the last card, it will fix the problem for the moment